# how to show the state space in SPIN

Tags: model-checking, spin, promela

The "Automata View" in iSpin (v. 1.1.4) shows .. exactly what?
It seems it is just a graph of the control flow of one process.

How would I get the full state space of the system?

E.g., in Ben-Ari: Principles of the Spin Model Checker, I want Figure 4.1.; or in [Overview](http://spinroot.com/spin/Doc/p40-ben-ari.pdf), I want Fig. 1.

Answer (score 0):

The generated `pan` program supports the `-d` and `-D` command-line arguments, which print state tables in ASCII resp. dot.

Comment: Have you tried this on the examples I mentioned? (I did, before I asked here.) These options produce nothing like the pictures I cited. Instead, it looks like a control flow diagram of an individual process.

Answer (score 0):

The book mentions (in Appendix 2) a tool `spinSpider` which is part of
[jspin](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/sci-tea/benari/software/jspin/index.html).
I could compile it from source, but did not manage to run it successfully
(error messages are unhelpful and the book does not explain usage)

Anyway, spinSpider seems deprecated in favour of VMC in [Erigone](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/sci-tea/benari/software/erigone/index.html).
It is not clear whether it has the same functionality (draw the complete state graph).

I could compile it but not run, as VMC seems specific to Erigone, and incompatible with Spin, e.g. it says "Can't find file check.pml.trc" -
is this the ".trail" file?